# CONSULTA DE SQL DEVELOPER HR

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola buenas necesito sacar la información del departamento con mayor cantidad de empleados y no puedo realizarlo adjunto código y tabla si me pueden ayudar se lo agradecería!

```
SELECT d.department_name
FROM employees e
inner join departments d
on d.manager_id = e.manager_id 
group by d.department_name
having max(e.department_id)=(SELECT max(count((department_id)))
                    FROM EMPLOYEES
                    group by department_id)
 ;
```

este codigo no me da informacion de nada el having si pero no puedo sacar el nombre del departamento que seria shiping si no me equivoco adjunto fotos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo con un `count` y limitar el registro a un solo elemento con `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT d.department_name, COUNT(*) as counting
FROM department d
INNER JOIN employees ON d.id = employees.department_id
GROUP BY (user.id)
ORDER BY counting desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hola no me arroga los datos necesarios

Comment: Que datos te arroja esa consulta, y cuáles son los datos que esperas obtener?